# Prevent showing Call.app GUI when auto answering call

Tags: ios, objective-c, hook, core-telephony

I have no idea how to hide Call.app gui when auto answering call. I'm hooking `CFNotificationCenterPostNotification` function and `kCTCallIdentificationChangeNotification` notification, then I'm calling `CTCallAnswer(call);` private function from `CoreTelephony` framework, then proceed with invoking original _`CFNotificationCenterPostNotification`. Call.app gui appears during this process. How to hide it from user?

Comment: You can try to hook `kCTCallStatusChangeNotification`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot programatically hide the call GUI, further to this calling private methods like CTCallAnswer will get your app rejected upon review,

Sorry about that.

Comment: I'm developing app for cydia, not for App Store

Comment: That's cool, however It's not possible to remove the call GUI programmatically to my knowledge.

Comment: I've just completed it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a way to hide the GUI. You should look into the MobileSubstrate and runtime hooking. The GUI you're talking about is a part of the Springboard/backboardd binaries.
The way to go: 
Springboard classes

```
BBDataProviderManager (iOS 7, to hook the "com.apple.mobilephone.incomingcall" plugin)
BBServer (iOS 6, to hook the "com.apple.mobilephone.incomingcall" plugin)
SBPluginManager (iOS 5)
SBAwayCallController (iOS 4 direct class to display the call GUI)
```

com.apple.mobilephone.incomingcall classes

```
MPTelephonyManager
```